# How to find a row-wise intersection of 2d numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I look for an efficient way to get a row-wise intersection of two two-dimensional numpy ndarrays. There is only one intersection per row. For example:

```
[[1, 2], ∩ [[0, 1], -> [1,
 [3, 4]]    [0, 3]]     3]
```

In the best case zeros should be ignored:

```
[[1, 2, 0], ∩ [[0, 1, 0], -> [1,
 [3, 4, 0]]    [0, 3, 0]]     3]
```

My solution:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1, 2],
                 [3, 4]])
arr2 = np.array([[0, 1],
                 [0, 3]])
arr3 = np.empty(len(arr1))

for i in range(len(arr1)):
    arr3[i] = np.intersect1d(arr1[i], arr2[i])

print(arr3)
# [ 1.  3.]
```

I have about 1 million rows, so the vectorized operations are most preferred. You are welcome to use other python packages.

Comment: If you found a solution (which looks right, in my humble opinion, and also vectorized), please post it as a solution and "accept" it so it's visible that the question has an accepted answer. Also, the `pandas` and `scipy` tags aren't relevant here.

Comment: You don't have to use a loop here, you can just transpose the arrays: `np.intersect1d(arr1.transpose(),arr2.transpose()).transpose()`

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Vectorization allows to execute similar operations simultaneously on a bunch of data. Your solution has the `for` loop so it's executed line by line. I accept solution which use `scipy` and `pandas` packages as well. Try to read documentation for the `intersect1d` function. It is a coincidence that you get the same result. Try these arrays `[[1,2],[3,4]]` and `[[3,4],[1,2]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [np.apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html).
I wrote a solution that pads to the size of the arr1.
Didn't test the efficiency.

```
    import numpy as np

    def intersect1d_padded(x):
        x, y = np.split(x, 2)
        padded_intersection = -1 * np.ones(x.shape, dtype=np.int)
        intersection = np.intersect1d(x, y)
        padded_intersection[:intersection.shape[0]] = intersection
        return padded_intersection

    def rowwise_intersection(a, b):
        return np.apply_along_axis(intersect1d_padded,
                        1, np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1))

    result = rowwise_intersection(arr1,arr2)

    >>> array([[ 1, -1],
               [ 3, -1]])
```

if you know you have only one element in the intersection you can use

```
    result = rowwise_intersection(arr1,arr2)[:,0]

    >>> array([1, 3])
```

You can also modify intersect1d_padded to return a scalar with the intersection value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an elegant way to do it in `numpy`, but a simple list comprehension can do the trick:

```
[list(set.intersection(set(_x),set(_y)).difference({0})) for _x,_y in zip(x,y)]
```

Comment: I deleted my response since you just answered while i was posting it.

Comment: Yeah, that happens